# Vim copy and paste using the mouse

Tags: vim, copy, paste

The copy and paste (using the mouse, highlight then right click) doesn't work in my VIM.
Is there any option settable in the vimrc file to achieve this behaviour ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable mouse behavior. This can be done using

```
set mouse=a
```

here is the [doc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'mouse')

Comment: It is rather `set mouse=` to get back "right-click menu".

Comment: For all *vim newbies* (like me), there's a better answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140584/286615).